# Difference between "as regards" and "in regard to"

Tags: grammar

In my understanding the phrases "as regards" and "in regard to" are interchangeable, but an editor once corrected the former to the latter in my writing. May I ask what is the difference? The sentence in my writing was as follows:

(original ver)
**As regards** your proposal submitted last week, our team has formed some opinions which are summarised here

(corrected ver)
**In regard to** your proposal submitted last week, our team has formed some opinions which are summarised here

Comment: Include references, preferably from standard English language dictionaries. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as_regards and https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with_(or_in_or_having)_regard_to

Comment: Btw, it is "in **regard** to," not "in **regards** to." The editor is wrong at least on that count.

Comment: I have corrected these in the title and original question, so the correct forms can be found by search.

Comment: @JohnLawler - It's one thing to correct the English in a question but if the question is specifically about which of two quoted phrases is correct shouldn't that be left as is and your correction be provided as part of an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *in regard to* when refering to a new subject.

Use *as regards* when continuing from a previous related section, when contrasting with the foregoing, or when adding on something less important.

In the instant case, it may be that the text is the beginning of a message, which should not use *as regards*.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Kris, yes, the text is the beginning of the message. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**In regard to your...** is correct.

**As regards your...** is correct but sounds bad to me.

**Regarding your...** is correct and even better.

Comment: Many thanks Martin, but I find "As regards" is recorded in the Cambridge Dictionary:https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/as-regards

Comment: Aha! I've updated my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks Martin, so maybe "As regards" is seldomly used by native speakers, but it is grammatical.

Comment: @Jane Btw, the **-ly** in *seldomly* is unnecessary, as *seldom* serves the same purpose.

Comment: Note that the idiom is _in regard to_, with **singular** _regard_, not *_in regards to_. On the other hand, the idiom _as regards_ **does** have a final _-s_, but it's not plural, because the _regard_ in this idiom is a verb, not a noun, and the _-s_ marks it as being a third person singular present tense verb.